# Reference to react-navigation throws error on import. Do I need webpack?

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I'm following the hello world tutorial for react-navigation on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html.

Adding the following line in one of my components:

```
import {  createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
```

throws an error:

> ./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/ResourceSavingSceneView.js
>   SyntaxError:
>   D:\redirectadministrator\redirectadmin\node_modules\@react-navigation\native\dist\ResourceSavingSceneView.js:
>   Unexpected token (35:11)

I'm not using yarn but npm. The packages in the tutorial are correctly installed.

My package.json:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-native": "^0.57.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.9",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1"
  },
```

Thanks!!

Comment: did you created your app with `react-native-cli` if yes you already have webpack

Comment: are you building `react-native` app ?

Comment: No, I ran create-react-app.

Comment: In your package.json you have mixed packages for web and for native mobile app and I not sure which one your are trying to build ?

Comment: `react-navigation` is package for `react-native` and has nothing to do with browsers

Comment: Mmm ok! I want it to be a desktop only app....

Comment: with `react-native` you can build native app for android and ios. By saying desktop do you mean app for a browser, because you can build and native desktop apps with frameworks based on `react`

Comment: @Nedko thanks! Do you think webpack is included in create-react-app ?

Comment: yes it is, but you wont see it in your package.json, it is used internally